# Firewalld is running, I can acccess unallowed kubernetes exposed port?

Tags: networking, rhel, nat, firewalld, kubernetes

I have a Kubeadm based Kubernetes cluster. Firewalld is running on all nodes on the cluster.

I expose a nginx service via NodePort service, that on theory should be accessible via all nodes on the cluster.

Firewalld is enabled so I can not access the service on the most nodes, except one. The node that runs the container. I can access the NodePort service on the node that hosts the container, across the cluster, even though firewalld is open. How?

My theory is NAT Masquerading is being on, but still is this expected behaviour?

Nodes: RHEL 8.4
Kubeadm version 1.28

Comment: I guess the kind of (blocked) flow depends on the CNI plugin in place. You should probably disable firewalld and install your own custom rules. Else there's this doc: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/using-kubernetes/#_creating_a_kubernetes_cluster_with_kubeadm_using_fedora_rpms  with a link to required ports https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/ports-and-protocols/ . But if you change CNI plugins, requirements might change.